# Elasticsearch failing to work with MongoDB river

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the MongoDB river (v2.04) with elasticsearch (v1.X) and while it installs, the river seems to fail when trying to index the data. Further, it prevents Elasticsearch from starting properly upon reboot of the server. The error in parsing data is:

```
[2014-11-14 11:19:08,625][WARN ][river                    ] [Tommy] failed to create river [mongodb][mongodb]
org.elasticsearch.common.settings.NoClassSettingsException: Failed to load class with value [mongodb]
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.spawnModules(RiverModule.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.add(ModulesBuilder.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService.createRiver(RiversService.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:275)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$1.run(TransportAction.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mongodb
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.elasticsearch.river.RiverModule.loadTypeModule(RiverModule.java:73)
    ... 9 more
```

The river setup looks like:

```
PUT /_river/mongodb/_meta
{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
      "servers":[
        {"host":"IPADDRESS","port":27017}
      ],
      "db": "database",
      "collection": "collection",
      "gridfs": true
    }, 
    "index": {
      "name": "items", 
      "type": "item" 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you did the same mistake as I did.

You not only need to install the dependency by issuing following:

```
plugin --install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.4.1
```

You also need to instal the river itself:

```
plugin --install com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.6
```

Elastic search looks for a class name by the value of type.